# How to exit Firefox kiosk mode?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, fullscreen, kiosk

I've set up Firefox on Ubuntu to run in kiosk (full-screen) mode. This means the user can visit only the predefined URLs. That works fine.

Now I want to set up a second machine the same way, but I cannot remember how I set up the first one. Since I cannot access the menu or the address field, there's no easy way to lookup up the configuration.

Any ideas on how to get the first machine back to normal mode or to find out the Firefox extension or configuration option used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After all I found that I can start Firefox in safe mode, which starts it with alle extensions switched off. This Mozilla knoledge base [article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_mode) describes how to do that for your os.

In safe mode I could see that the kiosk mode was done with the [R-Kiosk](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/r-kiosk/) add-on.

Answer (score 2):

The question asks about exiting kiosk mode for the purpose of identifying the settings to see how it was set up so it can be replicated.  This add-on will accomplish the kiosk mode for you:  [mKiosk: Public Firefox Kiosk Multimedia](https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/mkiosk/)

Addon description:

> Public Firefox Kiosk Mode with optional Tabs Guides for Access Point.
>   Complete solution. Block downloads/addon, bookmarks, reset kiosk
>   inactivity, retry on errors, restricted interface, show favorites as
>   buttons and more.

Answer (score 1):

If you press F11 firefox will exit fullscreen/kiosk mode

Comment: Not really. It only leaves fullscreen mode if has been enabled with F11. This is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu/Windows 10 run in terminal/cmd:

```
firefox -url about:addons
```

Disable R-Kiosk addon. Restart Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Its known its possible to run the Firefox in Kiosk mode by:

- Start FF and after than F11
- or start FF directly in Kiosk Mode by
  firefox --kiosk

Left the Kiosk Mode you can do by follow workaround:

- Its known F11 dont disable any more the Kisk Mode or dont do it in any more in all versions.
- Save you open Tabs if you like by Strg + Shift + D
- Change to other x windows tab on same screen, now you get bac a taskbar and start-program menu.
- Now you can close the FF which are in Kiosk Mode by Taskbar or if you like by terminal by kill, pkill and other sorts of kill
- If your FF have any misconfiguration which start allways in Kiosk Mode, you can start FF in Save Mode by firefox -save-mode for fixing this by p.e. about:config

Answer (score 0):

If your system opens kiosk mode inside a window manager / desktop environment (e.g. GNOME Shell, KWin/KDE, muffin/cinnamon, ...) you can try global shortcuts of that window manager or desktop environment to close the firefox window, e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

If that  doesn't help, you should always be able to ...

- open a tty (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>)
- log in
- run `killall firefox`
- Then go back to your graphical session (e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> or e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, depending on the system)